# Using match with response with content type as text/plain

Tags: karate

According to documentation - response is automatically available as a JSON, XML or String object depending on what the response contents are.

In my case I have the response with content type as text/plain

```
My server response is
["a.b.c:must match \"(\\d{4}(0[1-9"]
```

This works where I convert the string to response and then verify (I have escaped all the backslash)

```
 * string responseString = response
 * match responseString contains '["a.b.c match \\"(\\\\d{4}(0[1-9"]'
```

This fails. When response is also available as string then why is this failing

```
* match response contains '["a.b.c match \\"(\\\\d{4}(0[1-9"]'
```

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $[*], actual: ["a.b.c match \"(\d{4}(0[1-9"], expected: '["a.b.c:must match \"(\d{4}(0[1-9"]', reason: actual value does not contain expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste the below into a fresh Scenario and see it working for yourself. It should help you resolve your problem:

```
* string response = '["a.b.c:must match \"(\\d{4}(0[1-9"]'
* match response contains '["a.b.c:must match \"(\\d{4}(0[1-9"]'
* assert response.contains('["a.b.c:must match \"(\\d{4}(0[1-9"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have a solution that works which I had mentioned where I convert the response to string and then I do contains. I am just trying to understand as why its not working without the conversion. Assert response.contains failed with or without escaping backslash.
1 < Connection: close
1 < Content-Length: 94
1 < Content-Type: text/plain
1 < Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2018 04:18:18 GMT
1 < Server: secretServer
[
  "a.b.c:must match \"(\\d{4}(0[1-9"
]   
    * string responseString = response
    * match responseString contains '["a.b.c:must match \\"(\\\\d{4}(0[1-9"]'

Comment: Also if i just do a match like  this then that will also fail. I am just trying to understand in what all scenario's the response is converted to string and string can be matched via contains . Since in this case i am just trying to match a string to response I am assuming this should work  * match response contains 'a.b.c:must match'

Comment: @SauravKumar can't understand your question. you are a smart guy :P see if you can figure out by looking at the code. and have I ever referred you to this page :) https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue